# EC2 ubuntu launch node server on reboot not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, startup

I'm trying to launch an express app when my ec2 machine starts. I've a startup script that is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "will reroute traffic" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs

sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

echo "will kill node" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs

if pgrep node &> /dev/null ; then killall -KILL node ; fi
if pgrep nodejs &> /dev/null ; then killall -KILL nodejs ; fi

echo "will run node server" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs
cd server && npm install && npm run build && npm run start </dev/null &>/dev/null &
echo "has run node server" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs
```

If I launch it from the console, it starts the server, exits and the server runs fine.

To launch it, I've added those lines to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
rm -f /home/ubuntu/log.logs
echo "will run" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs
/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/startup.sh
echo "has run" >> /home/ubuntu/log.logs
```

After rebooting, the server is not responding and it looks like it has not started (the server logs ticks when running that are not there)

the output in `log.logs` looks fine:

```
will run
will will reroute traffic
will kill node
will run node server
has run node server
has run
```

so everything seems to have been executed, but the node app is not running, which I confirmed by running `top | grep node` that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cheap (or free) AWS VMs got CPU/network throttled causing npm installs etc. to fail.  Maybe use a VPS that is a better value or try `yarn`.  Also make it log the npm stuff to a file instead of dev/null.

Comment: Good advice on logging. Turned out that root doesn't know about npm, even if after becoming root, I run the script as `ubuntu`: `su -c ./startup.sh - ubuntu` raises the error `npm: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I installed `npm` and `node` through [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), and that nvm adds a script to `.bashrc` that will load those libraries. To start my script on reboot, I was using cron that is not sourcing `.bashrc`. Additionally, the default `.bashrc` on AWS EC2 ubuntu instances starts with a check on wether it's been run from a terminal or not, and escape it it's not been run from a terminal. So sourcing it from cron has no effect.

I didn't see that since the failing line

```
cd server && npm install && npm run build && npm run start
```

was not logging anything

I ended up manually sourcing the path to `npm` and `node`